# Reset sequence number monthly

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

VL/11/2014/050 to VL/12/2014/001

```
    <record id="seq_new_lead" model="ir.sequence">
        <field name="name">Visit Log</field>
        <field name="code">lead</field>
        <field name="prefix">VL/%(month)s/%(year)s/</field>
        <field name="interval number">1</field>
        <field name="interval units">months</field>
        <field name="padding">3</field>

    </record>
```

but it's not working. It should reset automatically at every month and start with 001.

Comment: Hi, did your find a solution for your problem ?

Answer (score 3):

You need this module:
[OpenERP ir sequence autoreset](https://github.com/buke/openerp-ir-sequence-autoreset)
It was very helpful to me. It works with standard implementation but if you need working with **no_gap** implementation you will have to code a little by your own like I did, I can help you if you ask.

I know it's late for answering but maybe someone need this now.